# python regex filter some html tag from a string

Tags: python, regex

I need process a string look like this:

```
original_str="SnO<sub>2</sub>solution-based (a<100 <sup>o</sup> AAAC>u_test)abcdhhhh"
```

The rule is that replace the

```
 "<" or ">" to "&lt;" or "&gt;" if they are not part of a HTML tag.
PS:The string only has <sup></sup><sub></sub> html tag
```

So the processed string should be:

```
process_str="SnO<sub>2</sub>solution-based (a&lt;100 <sup>o</sup> AAAC&gt;u_test)abcdhhhh"
```

I do not know how to use regular expression to handle this case.

Comment: You might want to read famous "parse html with regular expressions" answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6642340

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use regex for parsing HTML - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/66349) for details.

Instead use a fault tolerant HTML parser to read the string, then generate compliant output.

```
In [7]: import bs4

In [8]: original_str="SnO<sub>2</sub>solution-based (a<100 <sup>o</sup> AAAC>u_test)abcdhhhh"

In [9]: soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(original_str, 'lxml')

In [10]: print(soup)
<html><body><p>SnO<sub>2</sub>solution-based (a&lt;100 <sup>o</sup> AAAC&gt;u_test)abcdhhhh</p></body></html>
```

If you need just the fragment you originally posted, use something like

```
In [18]: soup.body.p.renderContents()
Out[18]: 'SnO<sub>2</sub>solution-based (a&lt;100 <sup>o</sup> AAAC&gt;u_test)abcdhhhh'
```

Comment: Thanks! bs4 is very powerful library.As far as I know, the string only has<sup><sub>html tag, so maybe use the regex to solve this problem will be more simple?

Comment: I got this result using your code:SnO<sub>2</sub>solution-based (ao AAAC&gt;u_test)abcdhhhh

Comment: @EvanZhang Check if you have lxml installed maybe?